# POP change to IMAP

Tags: imap

I changed from POP to IMAP a few years ago. My difficulty is that I cannot access with my iPad and iPhone the emails/folders on my mac that were established with the POP setting. The IMAP emails are fine between all three.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

That's the way POP and IMAP work. Once POP emails are downloaded and deleted from the server, they are stored locally and can only be accessed on the device that downloaded them. To make them accessible on other devices you have to upload them to IMAP folders.